# Does sudo apt install command also update an already installed app?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt, software-installation

I'm new to Linux OS distributions and I came up with a question when I had to update my Visual Studio Code today. I've searched for some solutions to update it through my terminal and every solution involved applying the command `sudo apt install code`. So here is my question, if I already have the application installed I can simply "install it again"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can, `apt install` will install the latest available package (according to its local indexes, so run `apt update` beforehand), upgrading if a previous version is already installed.

Quoting [the man page](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/apt/apt-get.8):

> install is followed by one or more packages desired for installation or upgrading.

Basically, `apt install package` will result in the currently-available version of `package` being installed, whether that involves a “new” installation or an upgrade.

As far as upgrades go, I recommend running `apt upgrade` instead of upgrading packages individually — it will upgrade all upgradable packages, ensuring your system is kept up-to-date.