# Upgrade certbot on Debian Jessie

Tags: debian, upgrade, backports, certbot

Hi i have a machine based on Debian Jessie running an apache web server along with `certbot 0.10.2`.

Due to this message i've received:

> As of June 1, 2021, you are no longer be able to renew your
> certificates using ACMEv1. You should upgrade to an ACMEv2 compatible
> client, or certificate issuance will fail.

I would like to upgrade to an ACMEv2 compatible version of certbot.

what i have done so far is:

```
echo 'deb http://archive.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/backport.list

echo 'Acquire::Check-Valid-Until no;' > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/no-check

apt update
```

Now, for what i know, i should be able to run:

```
apt-get install python-certbot-apache -t jessie-backports
```

and install the latest backported release, but since i already have certbot installed and also i have certificates issued, i would like to **upgrade** instead of install.

It is possible to do some kind of `-only-upgrade` on a single package using `backports`, or at least unistall the old version of certbot without deleting issued certificates?

**PS:** i have seen somehting like `sudo apt -t jessie-backports upgrade` to update the entire system, but i don't know if it's possible to use on single package

Thank you very mutch in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you to everyone for the support.

I finally solved the problem, using a different **ACME client** as suggested [here](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/client-options/)

Even though the procedure to install a certificate is [quite easy](https://github.com/acmesh-official/acme.sh), i want to share my steps:

First install the client:

```
wget -O -  https://get.acme.sh | sh -s email=my@example.com
```

> After the installation, you must close the current terminal and reopen
> it to make the alias take effect.

> **NB:** the installation also create **daily cron job** to check and renew the certs if needed, so, if you have other certbot task
> scheduled into the crontab, remove it.  if you don't have any
> cronjobs, means the renew task is automated, so, you have two options:
>
> - issue `certbot delete` to delete the old certificate interactively
> - just rename the `/etc/letsencrypt/renewal/example.com.conf` file, If you don't want to delete it.
>
> Anyway do this only at the end of the process, when everything is
> working right.

since i'm on **apache server** and i needed **2 domains (naked and full)** i have used the apache module like this:

```
acme.sh --issue --apache -d example.com -d www.example.com
```

if everything goes right, this should have created the certificates (check the console for the current path).

now it's time to install the certificates so i created a folder to store it:

```
mkdir -p /etc/apache2/certificates/example.com
```

then i have added the belows lines in the `example.com-le-ssl.conf` *(make a backup first ;-))* to reflect the imminent changes, and removed the old lines created by letsencrypt:

```
SSLEngine on

SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/certificates/example.com/cert.pem
SSLCertificateChainFile  /etc/apache2/certificates/example.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/certificates/example.com/privkey.pem

SSLProtocol             all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLCipherSuite          ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA
SSLHonorCipherOrder     on
SSLCompression          off

SSLOptions +StrictRequire
```

finally i have issued the command to install the certificates and reload the apache server

```
acme.sh --install-cert -d example.com \
--cert-file /etc/apache2/certificates/example.com/cert.pem \
--key-file /etc/apache2/certificates/example.com/privkey.pem \
--fullchain-file /etc/apache2/certificates/example.com/fullchain.pem \
--reloadcmd "service apache2 force-reload"
```

Answer (score 0):

The package `python-certbot-apache` isn't available for jessie-backports, you need to upgrade your Debian release to Stretch or Buster.

[Package search.](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=python-certbot-apache)

Comment: Jessie backports isn’t included in the package search. `python-cerbot-apache` *is* available there. (Look in the [index](http://archive.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie-backports/main/binary-amd64/Packages.xz).)

Comment: @GAD3R hi, why the official doc say to use it? https://wiki.debian.org/LetsEncrypt#Jessie_.28Debian_8.x.29_Howto

Answer (score 0):

You try to get certbot-auto working: https://github.com/certbot/certbot/blob/master/certbot-auto

It is no longer supported aswell, and it will require some fiddling with the python dependencies too on Jessie, and commenting out some checks in the script itself, but I am successfully using this on a Jessie system that sadly can't be upgraded yet:

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/certbot/certbot/1.11.x/certbot-auto
chmod +x certbot-auto

in 894 add:
DEPRECATED_OS=0

in 1753 change:
Bootstrap To BootstrapDebCommon

Run: NO_SELF_UPGRADE=1 ./certbot-auto
```

Invoke certbot-auto via its full path instead of certbot and the envvar, also in your renew cron.

Beware that this is very hacky and may obviously break again if dependencies, packages, or API things change. This also does NOT receive (security) updates (nor does Jessie itself).

Comment: please, would you like to explane the entire process to make it work?

Comment: I edited my answer with a working procedure in a clean Jessie env quickly started in Docker

Comment: this one is not supported anymore...

Answer (score 0):

```
apt-get install python-certbot-apache -t jessie-backports
```

will upgrade `python-certbot-apache` if it’s already installed in an older version; the use of the verb `install` doesn’t mean that the package will be installed from scratch.

See [Does sudo apt install command also update an already installed app?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/654007/86440)

Comment: thested it but after all gives me error...